# Can we pass arguments to a .sql file in SAP HANA?

Tags: hana

I want to know, can we pass arguments to the sql file. If yes, then how

Please help.

Comment: The feature may be added in next versions

Comment: If using a stored procedure, you could pass parameters to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there is no feature for this.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say, we have an sql file (test.sql), containing a simple select of two parameters - param1 and param2. Parameter names should be prefixed with &.

```
echo "select '&param1' param1, '&param2' param2 from dummy;" > test.sql
```

Now let's pass some arguments, using the HANA client hdbsql.The -V option is used, followed by parameter name, equal sign and parameter value. In case the value contains spaces, it should be quoted as shown here:

```
hdbsql ... -V param1=value1 -V "param2='another value'" -I test.sql
```

The result is:

```
PARAM1,PARAM2
"value1","another value"
```

Comment: Can you please format your code and add a little more details or explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Another exemple :

the z:\temp\hana_query.sql file content :

```
SELECT 
"HANAOTIF"."CD_PERIOD" AS "CD_PERIOD",
"HANAOTIF"."CD_ORDER" AS "CD_ORDER",
"HANAOTIF"."CD_ORDER_ITEM" AS "CD_ORDER_ITEM",
"HANAOTIF"."CD_ORDER_TYPE" AS "CD_ORDER_TYPE",
"HANAOTIF"."CD_ORDER_ITEM_CAT" AS "CD_ORDER_ITEM_CAT"
FROM "mycompany.maestro.master.dashboarding::STAR_OTIF" "HANAOTIF"
WHERE "HANAOTIF"."CD_PERIOD" = &period
```

A powershell script running several call off the query asynchronously passing values from a list before the For-Each to the -ArgumentList using $_

```
$cmd={
param($yearmonth)
D:\Applications\sap\hdbclient\hdbsql.exe -U MAESTRO_PRD -o Z:\temp\hanaout_${yearmonth}.txt -I Z:\temp\hanasql_query.sql -m -V period=${yearmonth}
}

202101..202107 | ForEach-Object {
  Start-Job -ScriptBlock $cmd -ArgumentList $_
}

get-job
```